# Centering a node on screen with SKCameraNode [Swift]

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Ok so currently I have a node that can be thrown and dragged around. I also have a background picture that I created. I would like the screen to always have the ball in the middle x coordinate, but I also want the background image to always have the same position on the screen.

How can I do this?

Comment: If the ball and background are all centred to the camera, and this is the only way to see the screen and be in the screen, there'll be no apparent movement. Or I'm failing to understand you.

Answer (score 0):

Attach you background node to (0,0) on your `SKCameraNode` with a zPosition in the negative range, like -10

Now as for the ball, you need to attach this to your scene, then set the camera x position equal to the ball x position

so on your update method, just do `camera.position.x = ball.position.x`.  (If you sub classed ball, then I would override position on ball to set the camera, and avoid having to do it on the update loop)

Comment: ... background.position = CGPoint.zero

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. How do I set it to 0, 0 on my SKCameraNode?

Comment: Ok but if i put my background at 0, 0 then the camera will still move away from it.

Comment: no, you attach it to your camera at position 0,0  camera.addChild(background)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128216/discussion-between-josh-schlabach-and-knight0fdragon).